# extracting errors from logcat

Tags: android, logcat

How can I identify and understand an error from logcat ? I've got this log when I was trying to access to an element from a listView ( using AVD ) :

[image]

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have missed **Layout_width** attribute in your xml file . It is written there in java,lang.Runtime Exception log. Check it.

Comment: how could you understand that ?

Comment: See in every logcat wherever your encounter Caused by: Statement , they are clickable these statements can re-direct you to the main cause. Also try to read logs clearly they keep track of every thing. Like in this it is written , in line no. 2 there is Layout_width missing. in About_us

Answer (score 2):

You must supply a layout width attribute.
See the line "Caused by: ... Binary XML file line #12:"

Comment: 8 minutes to validate this.

Answer (score 0):

Errors are preceeded by Caused by and then "error with line number" Here the error is in xml file in the line number 12 where you havn't provided the `layout_width` attribute.

Answer (score 0):

I think you missing layout_width attribute in xml file which xml file use in your com.example.listview.AboutUs class so it's gave you run time exception...